Random Data Loss in Redis Cluster During Bulk Operations
Random Data Loss in Redis Cluster During Bulk Operations
Issue Description
I'm experiencing random data loss in my Redis cluster setup. Here's a detailed breakdown of the scenario:
Setup

Local Redis cluster environment
NestJS application
Main async function containing 13 sub-functions
Each function handles setting ~100,000 records to Redis in a loop

Observed Behavior

All data successfully passes through the application logic and reaches the Redis SET operation
Random loss of approximately 100-1,000 records
No pattern in which records are lost

Environment Details

Each cluster node allocated:

1 core CPU
600MB memory


Current memory usage: 100-200MB per node (well within limits)
No network connectivity issues observed

Current Configuration
environment.clusterMode
    ? new Redis.Cluster(
          [
              {
                  host: environment.redisCluster.clusterHost,
                  port: parseInt(environment.redisCluster.clusterPort),
              },
          ],
          {
              redisOptions: {
                  username: environment.redisCluster.clusterUsername,
                  password: environment.redisCluster.clusterPassword,
              },
              maxRedirections: 300,
              retryDelayOnFailover: 300,
          },
      )
    : new Redis({
          host: environment.redisHost,
          port: parseInt(environment.redisPort),
      })

Troubleshooting Done

Verified all data reaches the SET operation (no logical errors in application code)
Confirmed adequate memory allocation
Monitored cluster performance during operations
Checked network stability

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
